# Hardwired functions and GPU vs. CPU

Tags: graphics, gpu, hardware-acceleration

Why are some functions hardwired (mostly those used in games like swapping framebuffers)? What does the term hardware-accelerated mean?

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of hardwired in General-Purpose computing.

Hardware-accelerated means the application is developed to take advantage of accelerators on the system which the application is running on. Most conventional hardware-accelerators are GPUs found in most of desktop systems. In supercomputing, the term accelerator is referred to IBM PowerPC BQC, Intel Xeon Phi, GPUs, or FPGAs co-processors accelerating specific computations.

Comment: Don't forget about CPU-based acceleration pipelines, such as SSE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Comment: @ahmad Hardwired means implemented directly in the hardware (that's what I've leaned in the computer architecture class). Right?

Comment: @saadtaame The only hardwired I know is the control-unit design in CPUs. This design is an alternative to microprogram. You can further detail about it [here][ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit ].